# How does AngularJS get the values for data, status, etc in function parameter?

Tags: angularjs, promise

Sorry this may be a dumb question but it isn't obvious to me:

```
function login(email, password){
      return $http.post('/api/v1/login/', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }).then(loginSuccessFn, loginErrorfn);

      function loginSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config){
        Authentication.setAuthenticatedAccount(data.data);

        window.location = '/'
      }

      function loginErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('Failed');
        console.log(data)
      }
    }
```

This is a snippet from a tutorial I'm doing, If I need to post more I will.
In the line `function loginSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config)` where is the function getting the `data`, `status`, `headers`, and `config` values from? `console.log(data)` works, I'm just not sure where 'data' is being used anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: 
Those are properties of response object of returned promise from your http call.

Details:
HTTP request returns a promise that contains a response object. The response object not only contains the properties that you mentioned in your question but according to the angular documentation also has statusText and xhrStatus properties. Below you can find expalanation of each property copied from the angular documentation.

- data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
- config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
- xhrStatus – {string} – Status of the XMLHttpRequest (complete, error, timeout or abort).

You can find more information about this subject in the following page.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http